# Comparing trees with different leaf sets (different number and label of leaf nodes)

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, comparison, phylogeny

I have hierarchical data from file/ folder structures which i use to build trees. I am now trying to compare these trees with random ones and amongst themselves.

To compare to random trees I can preserve the number and label of the leaf nodes and use traditional tree distance metrics (For instance Robinson-Foulds distance). Nonetheless to compare different trees from different data ( with different number of leaves and labels ) I have no idea which metric/ algorithm to use. Any suggestions?

thanks!

PS- the goal with the comparison would be to establish how similar is the topology between these trees and see which clusters may exist (and hence add some piece of evidence on the thoughts of the generating mechanisms behind the folder structure).

Comment: I think this too vague certainly for me to understand exactly what you want the result of the comparison to be. Can you elaborate with a small example?

Comment: I think she wants a similarity metric for unrooted, unlabelled trees. The first possibility that comes to mind (and bear in mind this is just something I'm thinking up on the spot) is to pick an arbitrary root for each tree, then use a rooted tree isomorphism algorithm to find the maximal matching between the nodes of the two rooted trees. Do this for all ~n^2 pairs of possible roots, and take as your distance the smallest number of unmatched nodes, normalized by the total number of nodes in the two trees.

Comment: hi Andy, thanks for your answer. I was thinking the tree as rooted since it always starts from the root folder and branches out from there but i suppose i can also unroot it and apply your suggestion. Do you have any reference explaining the tree isomorphism algorithm for unlabelled trees? thanks again! Ps-working on an example to post!